# Update query not updating records

Tags: php

I am totally confused as to why my update query is not updating the records. There are no errors in inspector console. If I run the query in `phpmyadmin` substituting the vars with actual values it works fine.

I have tried coding the vars like this in query: `'".$name."'` and also like i have it now. All field names are correct and all values are being passed to php correctly. I would be grateful if someone could point out my error as it is driving me nuts. Many thanks

```
<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","domain");

if($conn === false) {
die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

  $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['idcon']);
  $company = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['companycon']);
  $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['namecon']);
  $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['emailcon']);
  $phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, _POST['phonecon']);
  $fax = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['faxcon']);
  $mobile = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['mobilecon']);

  $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE contact_con SET idcode_con = '$company', name_con = '$name', email_con = '$email', phone_con = '$phone', fax_con = '$fax', mobile_con = '$mobile' WHERE id_con='$id'");

  mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

Comment: did you checked it by executing manually in the phpmyadmin?

Comment: could you post html

Comment: $id prolly don't contain a value. Or contains a value that is not in table.

Comment: @vikalp please see my original question

Comment: @KarloKokkak In my question i put All field names are correct and all values are being passed to php correctly. Thanks

Comment: @user1532468 What does a mysqli_error($conn); return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using [prepared queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php), also you have a typo `_POST['phonecon']`.

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "domain");

// check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    exit("Connect failed: ". mysqli_connect_error());
}

// create a prepared statement
$stmt = $conn->prepare("
    UPDATE contact_con 
    SET idcode_con = ?,
        name_con = ?, 
        email_con = ?, 
        phone_con = ?, 
        fax_con = ?, 
        mobile_con = ?
    WHERE id_con= ?
");

if ($stmt) {
    // bind parameters for markers
    $stmt->bind_param(
        "ssssssi", 
        $_POST['companycon'],
        $_POST['namecon'], 
        $_POST['emailcon'], 
        $_POST['phonecon'], 
        $_POST['faxcon'], 
        $_POST['mobilecon'],
        $_POST['idcon']
    );

    // execute query
    $stmt->execute();

    // close statement
    $stmt->close();
}

// close connection
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Many thanks Lawrence. I have been staring at that for hours lol. good spot on the typo.